# Parse specific xml comment in Python3

Tags: xml, python-3.x

I have a xml file containing *one* interesting comment, and I would like to parse it.

[Here](http://bugs.python.org/issue8277) I discovered how I can handle comments, but I don't know how to use them from my main app.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with open('xml_with_comments.xml', 'w') as f:
    f.write('''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <blah>node 1</blah>
        <!-- secret_content: Hello! -->
        <blah>node 2</blah>
        <!-- A standard comment -->
        <blah>node 3</blah>
    </root>
    ''')

class TreeBuilderWithComments(ET.TreeBuilder):
    def comment(self, data):
        if data.startswith(' secret_content: '):
            self.start(ET.Comment, {})
            self.data(data)
            self.end(ET.Comment)
            print('Secret content from TreeBuilderWithComments: ' + data[17:-1])

root = ET.parse('xml_with_comments.xml', parser=ET.XMLParser(target=TreeBuilderWithComments())).getroot()
for blah in root.findall('blah'):
    print(blah.text)
```

This outputs:

```
Secret content from TreeBuilderWithComments: Hello!
node 1
node 2
node 3
```

Now I would like to do something like `print(root.get_secret_content())`, which should print the first comment of the file begining by ' secret_content: '.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make an instance of `TreeBuilderWithComments()` inside the call to `ET.parse`, if you keep a reference to it you can use that instance to get the secret content:

```
 # do this first.
comment_handler = TreeBuilderWithComments()

root = ET.parse('xml_with_comments.xml',
                parser=ET.XMLParser(target=comment_handler)
               ).getroot()                # ^^ used here!

for blah in root.findall('blah'):
    print(blah.text)
```

Then you can implement `.get_secret_content` to your `TreeBuilderWithComments` class and use it on the `comment_handler` instance.

Comment: Thank you! I also modified TreeBuilderWithComments.comment(): `def comment(self, data): [\n] SECRET_CONTENT_KEY = 'secret_content: ' [\n] data = data.strip() [\n] if data.startswith(SECRET_CONTENT_KEY): [\n] self.secret_content = data[len(SECRET_CONTENT_KEY):]`. So _get_secret_content()_ is a simple getter.